# POST XML information using Python

Tags: python, xml, post, curl

I am creating a program in python that posts an XML file to a website's rest API to create a VCS root (this is what the website API documentation suggests).  My program creates an XML file, based on user input, posts it (using the requests library), then deletes the file.  Is there a way I can post the information contained in the XML file (mostly property values), without creating and deleting this temporary XML file? Can I post the information as a string or something? Examples in python or cURL could help.

Comment: use the `data`-attribute of requests.

Comment: @Daniel do you know where I can find some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the data-Attribute of `requests`:

```
from io import BytesIO
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

data = et.Element('some-xml')
tree = et.ElementTree(data)
payload = BytesIO()
tree.write(payload)
r = requests.post(url, data=payload.getvalue())
```